# Elegant way to collapse an empty div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Suppose I have a page with the following content:

```
<div><p>Some content</p></div>
<div id="container"><p class="destroy">Some content that will go away.</p></div>
<div if="footer"><p>Some footer content.</p></div>
```

And some jQuery:

```
jQuery(".destroy").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).fadeOut('slow');
})
```

How do avoid the 'jump' of the footer once the content goes away? I would like it to smoothly slide into place.

Here's [the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/qJFnc/1/). Here's [how I would like it to work](http://jsfiddle.net/kQugU/1/) (but without specifying a height).

Caveats:

1. The #container will vary in width and height, as it's contents will be dynamic.
2. The solution must be minimal but readable.
3. jQuery and the jQuery UI are included.
4. Bonus points for an elegant universal solution (detects all empty div's, and smoothly collapses them).

Comment: Why are you fading out the `.destroy` content and not the `#container`?  Does the `#container` have other content?  Also, `.slideUp()` rather than `.fadeOut()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get the "jump" because [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) sets `display:none` when the animation is completed.

Use [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) instead and fade the opacity to `0`. You can then chain that with `slideUp()` to get the exact behaviour your specified as *"how I would like it to work"*

```
jQuery('.destroy').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow', 0).slideUp();
})
```

Proof of the pudding: http://jsfiddle.net/qJFnc/4/

---

If there's nothing else in `#container`, you could call `slideUp()` on that instead:

```
jQuery('.destroy').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
        jQuery('#container').slideUp();
    });
})
```

More pudding: http://jsfiddle.net/qJFnc/5/

Comment: I give you props for getting me 90% of the way there... I changed it to this:

`jQuery('.destroy').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow', 0).slideUp(function(){ 
            jQuery(this).remove()});
        })`

Answer (score 1):

Animate it to zero and then remove on the callback

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qJFnc/2/

```
jQuery('.destroy').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).animate({height : 0}, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    })
})
```

------------------Edit:

To use the fade affect with no CSS height you need to use the fadeTo() as it doesnt remove the element like fadeOut does. Then on the callback of that slide the element up.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qJFnc/10/

Updated Source:

```
jQuery('.destroy').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).fadeTo(500,0, function() {
        $(this).slideUp();
    })
})
```

Comment: I'm afraid I like the fade effect for my application, or else this would be a great solution.

Comment: A simpler way to get the same effect is to use `.slideUp()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will get dynamic height and set it to css.

http://jsfiddle.net/kQugU/2/

```
jQuery('.destroy').click(function(){
    jQuery('#container').css("height", jQuery('#container').height());
    jQuery(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
        jQuery('#container').slideUp();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
$(".destroy").click(function(){
    $("#container").animate({opacity : 0},400,function(){
        $(this).slideUp(100);
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R779K/

The animate function has a callback that is run AFTER the main animation completes. You can have whatever you want in there.

Opacity only set's the opacity propriety, leaving the display:block intact for the div, so when you fade out it looks as if the #content is gone, and the footer is slowly taking up the blank space.